# How to display multiple items on one graph?

Tags: java, sql, swing, netbeans, graph

I have designed an inventory/sales information system using a Swing GUI for a computer store (fictional). One of the features is to display a basic bar graph of how certain products have sold in a year.

The data is called from a MySQL database called `dbsales` and the category of products is selected using a jComboBox (`cboAnSales`).
I have a method (`public void graph()`) that has the coding to generate the graph.

The data for the items displays in textfields and the graph uses that information to display. The method is called inside the `cboAnSales`if statements for each category.

The problem now is it generates each item on its own graph. For example there are 7 items in the Cables category and when I select it, it generates 7 graphs (one for each item).
I need all 7 items to display on one single graph.

How can I achieve this?

Here is the Cables section of the cboAnSales:

```
private void cboAnSalesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    if (cboAnSales.getSelectedIndex() == 1)
    { 
        try
        {
            String sql = "select * from dbsales where category ='" + "Cable" + "'";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = (Connection)
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/salventri","root","password");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql); 
            DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                String ID = rs.getString("pid");
                txtpid.setText(ID);
                String brand = rs.getString("pbrand");
                txtBrand.setText(brand);
                String name = rs.getString("pname");
                txtName.setText(name);
                String category = rs.getString("category");
                txtCategory.setText(category);
                String unitSold = rs.getString("usold");
                txtUnitsSold.setText(unitSold);
                graph();
            }       
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
    }
```

Here is the coding for my graph in the `public void graph()` method:

```
String unitsSold = txtUnitsSold.getText();
String brand = txtBrand.getText();
String name = txtName.getText();
String cat = txtCategory.getText();

DefaultCategoryDataset ddataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
ddataset.setValue(new Double(unitsSold), cat, brand + " " + name);

JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("Annual Sales Performance", cat, "Number of Units Sold", ddataset);
chart.getTitle().setPaint(Color.RED);
CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot();
p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.BLUE);
ChartFrame frame2 = new ChartFrame("Annual Sales", chart);
frame2.setVisible(true);
frame2.setSize(450,350);
```

Comment: Isn't there a dataset addvalue  or ... addSeries?

Comment: @D-Klotz I actually tried using an array to achieve this and posted that as another question but the answer I got was actually ideal for what I was asking here and it works. I just posted the answer below now. But thanks for responding :)

Answer (score 1):

With credit to WillShackleford, the solution to my question resulted in the following code in my `public void graph()`:

```
public void graph()
    {
       String year = cboAnnYear.getSelectedItem().toString();
       if(cboAnSales.getSelectedIndex() == 1) 
       {
        try
        {
            //declaring the type of category in the column
            String text = "Cable";
            //Select statement getting the row count
         String sql = "select count(category) from dbsales where category ='" + text + "'";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = (Connection)
            DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/salventri","root","password");
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("select * from dbsales where category=?");
            stmt.setString(1, text);
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            DefaultCategoryDataset ddataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
            while (rs.next()) 
            {
                ddataset.setValue(new Double(rs.getDouble("usold")),
            rs.getString("pbrand") + " " + rs.getString("pname"),
            rs.getString("syear"));
            }

             JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createBarChart3D("Annual Sales Performance", text, "Number of Units Sold", ddataset);
            chart.getTitle().setPaint(Color.RED);
            CategoryPlot p = chart.getCategoryPlot();
            p.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.BLUE);
            ChartFrame frame2 = new ChartFrame("Annual Sales", chart);
            frame2.setVisible(true);
            frame2.setSize(900,700);
            }
```